# I didn't ('go' or 'went') to party?

Tags: past-tense, verb-forms, do-support

> 1. I didn't **go** to party.
> 2. I didn't **went** to party.

Comment: possible duplicate of [did + present tense (or ) Past tense of the verb](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5473/did-present-tense-or-past-tense-of-the-verb)

Comment: Not a duplicate of the above-linked question, which is about the need to introduce "did" to make a question: "How you went to the party?" vs. "How did you go to the party?"

Answer (score 9):

> 1. I didn't **go** to (the) party
> 2. I didn't **went** to (the) party.

After the auxiliary verb *DO* the main verb must be in the *plain form*. This is the form you see in the dictionary. It does not have any tense. It is not past or present:

- *He doesn't **goes** to the gym. (ungrammatical - main verb in present tense)
- *He didn't **saw** the film. (ungrammatical - main verb in past tense)
- He doesn't **go** to the gym. (correct)
- He didn't **see** the film. (correct)

**The Original Poster's examples**

Example (1) is correct because the verb *go* is in the plain form after the auxiliary *do*. Example (2) is incorrect because *went* is a past form, not a plain form of the verb.

Comment: Example #1 would also be correct with the indefinite article depending on the context I think. "I didn't go to a party. I went to work." I'm not stalking you, by the way - these questions are in my review queue :)

Comment: +1 It'd be even better if you added in your answer why "I didn't go (to) party" and "I didn't go to the party" (or "a party") are different, even though the OP could find some clues in other answers.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I'm a bit strapped for time.But, if you wanted to, you could edit that info in - if the fancy takes you :)

Answer (score 3):

"I didn't go to party" could also be correct if you're talking about the reason you went somewhere...

"I went to Bermuda on a business trip.  I didn't go to party."

Answer (score 3):

This is a **rule** in English grammar:

The verb which comes after the *auxiliary verb* - "**did**", always will be the base form (that called "infinitive" form, meaning without any [inflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection) to the past tense). Therefore:

> I didn't **go** to the party.
>
> I didn't **meet** him.
>
> I didn't **know** him.
>
> I didn't **see** him.

As you can see, all of them are in the base form.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is correct, unless there's literally a place called "Party."

I didn't go to *the* party.

Also, it's **go** and not went because the auxiliary verb `did` means that `go` [does not change tenses](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/did-main-verb-base-form-or-past-tense-form).

Comment: Not *necessarily* true! : ) "Why did you go there?" - "I went there to party". "I didn't go to party, I went to study!"

Answer (score 0):

It must be "I didn't go".
"Did" is already in the past tense.
"Go" does not have to be in the past tense if "did" was already in the past tense.
You could say I went.
But you couldn't say I did not went.
You could say I went not.