# Which one is correct? "Do you enjoyed sports?" or "Did you enjoy sports?"

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, do-support

I'm trying to understand one thing about this sentence. Can anyone tell me the mistake? "Do you enjoyed sports?" For what I know, that sentence is in the past tense. Shouldn't that be a correct sentence?

Comment: A very close question, this one asks "didn''t go" or 
 "didn't went" https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/57783/i-didnt-go-or-went-to-party

Comment: The way you asked your question, unedited, tells me you're not an absolute beginner. It suggests that you have studied the basics of English, e.g. *"Shouldn't that be a correct sentence?"* and in the title **"Did you enjoy sports?”** moreover you're able to construct a complex phrase such as *"For what I know"* perfectly well and correctly. Perhaps you're confusing "**Do you enjoyed**...?" with "**Have you enjoyed**...?”?

Answer (score 2):

In all do-support constructions, and in all auxiliary verb (helper verb) constructions, the tense is indicated by the auxiliary verb (do, have, is) and not by the main verb (enjoy, enjoyed, enjoying)

**Do support**

For questions, negations, and the emphatic use of "do" in the present tense the structure is always "do/does/did" + base-form

> I didn't enjoy sports.  (past tense negation)

> He does enjoy sports.  (present tense, emphatic "do")

> Do we enjoy sports?  (present tense question)

> Did they enjoy sports? (past tense question)

So for your sentence the only grammatically correct form is

> Did you enjoy sports?

Answer (score 0):

#### No, "Do you enjoyed" is not correct.

"Enjoyed" is past tense. "Do" is present tense. The tenses conflict, so it's not a correct sentence. The proper way to phrase this idea would be "Have you enjoyed" or "Did you enjoy", for the past tense, or "Do you enjoy" for the present tense.

Comment: "The tenses conflict" is not an accurate description of why this is wrong. Matching the tenses leads to the completely **wrong** sentence "did you enjoyed...?"

Comment: @Laurel Those tenses don't match either. You have to use "have" with a past tense verb, not "did".

Comment: "Have with past tense verb leads to the incorrect "I have ate".  Take care here!

Comment: @JamesK "Eaten" is also past tense, and would be correct with "I have".

Comment: Eaten is a past participle and doesn't have tense.  Consider "The apples are eaten by the monkeys".  That is a present tense sentence!

Comment: "Eaten is a past participle and doesn't have tense" I dunno what the formal name for it is (participle might be right, I dunno), but it's still past tense. "The apple is eaten by the monkey" isn't idiomatic. You need to use an uncountable noun for that, like "The grain is eaten by the horses", or a plural, like "the apples are eaten by the monkey" - it starts in the past and continues on into the present.

Answer (score -1):

Neither are correct.

> "Do you enjoy sports?" is rather vague but correct English.

It is difficult to find a correct sentence with the combination of enjoyed and sports.

You could have enjoyed a specific sport when at college, but to have enjoyed sports is rather vague and I would argue incorrect. Basically the sentences are not complete.

> *I enjoyed several sports* during my time at college but I only excelled in track events.

Comment: I think this misses the point!  The question was not about the rhetorical impact of "Do you enjoy sports?" but the question is about how to structure a past tense question with do-support.

Comment: I am Sorry but I thought the question was "Which one is correct? “Do you enjoyed sports?” or “Did you enjoy sports?” which I answered. Then I showed my reasoning. If I had focused on the tense then I would have ignored the contextual implications.