# What is difference between these two sentences?

Tags: grammar

> What he did?

and:

> What did he do?

What is happen if we add one "DO" in the sentence, does it change the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: "What he did?" is not idiomatic English. Correct usage would be "What did he do? What did he say? What did he bring?" and the like.

Comment: 'What he did?' is acceptable as an echo question; it is unacceptable as an alternative for 'What did he do?'

Comment: You haven't just added a DO, you've also changed the order of the words.

Comment: "to die" sounds scheduled. "We are to die on Wednesday unless the mayor grants us a reprieve."

Comment: Possible **duplicate** of [did + present tense (or ) Past tense of the verb](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5473/did-present-tense-or-past-tense-of-the-verb)

Answer (score 0):

"What he do?" is not correct English. So, there technically isn't a difference, as one of the options doesn't exist. "What did he do?" is a question that asks what a person (he) did (and presumably finished) in the past.