# Which is correct? How did it all began/begin?

Tags: past-tense, infinitives, do-support

I'm confused between these two. Which is correct to use between

> 1. How did it all **began**? *or*
> 2. How did it all **begin**?

Answer (score 2):

Began is the simple past tense of begin. An example conversation using both of these is:

> "How did it all begin?"
>
> "It **began** when I first saw her face."

In the first sentence, because the verb uses the auxiliary verb "do", the past tense is conveyed by changing do to "did". An example in the present tense using "do":

> "How do I begin this?"
>
> "You **begin** by wrapping the string around your fingers."

More on the verb form to use with *do* can be found in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5473/did-present-tense-or-past-tense-of-the-verb).

Answer (score 1):

This is a **rule** in English grammar:

The verb which comes after the *auxiliary verb* - "**did**", always will be the base form (that called "infinitive" form, meaning without any [inflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection) to the past tense). Therefore:

> I didn't **begin** to do it.
>
> I didn't **meet** him.
>
> I didn't **know** him.
>
> I didn't **see** him.

As you can see, all of them are in the base form, rather than in the past tense form.

It's doesn't matter if your sentence is with wh questions or not, therefore it will be the same:

> How did he **begin** to do it.
>
> when did he **begin** to do it.