# I did as suggest but to no avail

Tags: verbs, tense-agreement

> I did as suggest but to no avail

Rule states with 'did' in sentence first form of verb is correct but above statement is quite unheard of. On the contrary,

> I did as suggested.

is very common. Please elaborate where I'm missing the link or what did I fail to get?

Comment: The statement in your title, is it what you're asking about? If so, it's ungrammatical because it should be "I did as suggested but to no avail".

Comment: @M.A.R. Yeah, i'm talking of the statement in title. Well I second your opinion but my confidence show cracks when i find these http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5473/did-present-tense-or-past-tense-of-the-verb   and http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/did-main-verb-base-form-or-past-tense-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your confusion. In your example **did** functions on its own and not as an auxiliary. In other words **suggest** is not a verb here, but an adjective. Consequently your sentence reads:

> I did as [it/I was] suggested but to no avail.